# Is it worth obfuscating email addresses on the web these days?

Tags: email, spam-prevention

There are [various ways](http://techblog.tilllate.com/2008/07/20/ten-methods-to-obfuscate-e-mail-addresses-compared/) to obfuscate email addresses on the web, but most of them don't work when you need to have a `mailto:` href.

I generally use `name[AT]domain.com`, because I think it's fairly obvious to the user what they have to do to get a real email address, but I wonder if there's any benefit to this (as it's easy to automate by a spammer). I'm aware of the services which hide the email address behind a captcha, but to me this is too much work for the user.

So, two questions:

1. Is there any way that (a) retains the use of `mailto:` links, (b) will stop spammers and (c) isn't too complicated for non-power users to work out?
2. Is it worth it? Do we just accept that spammers will find a way round it and just use Gmail?

**Edit:** I should mention that, in this specific case, I'm talking about the contact email address for the companies whose websites I'm making, on their websites.

Comment: Setting up a local contact form still seems like the simplest and safest bet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On websites I maintain, I consider it my **duty** to protect my user's email addresses. Spam is bad enough, I don't need to make it easy for the spammers.

At the same time, usability demands functional mailto links. My favorite method for achieving this is to use the free [SpamSpan](http://www.spamspan.com/) technique (at paranoia level 3). It is free, cross-browser, seems effective, and leaves easy-to-read text when JavaScript is disabled.

#### Sample HTML

```
<span class="spamspan">
<span class="u">user</span>
[at]
<span class="d">example [dot] com</span>
</span>
```

#### Result (JavaScript enabled)

[user@example.com](http://mailto%3auser@example.com)

#### Result (JavaScript disabled)

user [at] example [dot] com

Comment: Protect your users email addresses by only allowing other logged in users to view them, make displaying an email address a user option which is disabled by default. Don't screw up the web's semantics  through obfuscation

Comment: @Gaz - Web semantics is a noble cause, but my users don't want their email addresses taking part. Our use case requires that anonymous users be able to use the mailto links - logging in isn't an option. The technique I describe is a nice balance between obfuscation and usability.

Comment: you don't have to display an email address unless the user wants to have it displayed. At this point, restricting access to it is as lame as using JavaScript to prevent right-clicking.

Comment: I think this method is a great way of controlling spam while, as far as the user is concerned, providing a useful feature. I do not agree with @Gaz Davidson that this is as egregious as disabling right-clicking, since there is no perceivable difference to users. They simply have a mailto link, and that is what matters to them. And allowing them to hide their email address is good, but at the same time removes the ability for them to be contacted (provided that is at least one goal of the site). Thus, those that chose to make their email public lose out.

Comment: A spambot collects email addresses out of websites by searching the anchor tag with mailto: <a href="mailto:xx@xx.x">. This is easy for the bot.

But the spambot can also search for the class "spamspan" on websites in order to find this html tags: 
<span class="spamspan">
<span class="u">user</span>
[at]
<span class="d">example [dot] com</span>
</span>

The bot reads the content of the u class, of the d class and collects in this way all spamspan protected mail addresses from websites.

Spamspan in this way, using the classes 'spamspan, u, d', .. is NOT secure!

How to secure it?

Answer (score 5):

IMHO, there's no good reason to obfuscate emails. Spam filtering can be done quite well automatically by third party services so it's not really your or your users problem, yet retrieving a working email is a barrier however small in communication, which is.

Answer (score 3):

I doubt that it's ever been worth it.  Email obfuscation has been entirely based on second guessing the spammers and imagining what the scrapers will and won't do.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever I sign up for a new account, I use a unique email address for that account. I *know* which sites are bad at giving out my address and which sites keep it confidential, and if an address starts receiving spam I assume the worst about that company (IE, that they've resold my personal info as opposed to lax security allowing it to be seen by a spider).

Your users shouldn't have to take such measures. You should be keeping their personal information as private as possible unless they explicitly ask you to do otherwise.

It's difficult to offer advice as the need to display user information varies from site to site. As a general rule, I would introduce a captcha in the login process, and then only show the email address within a properly marked-up mail-to link to logged in users. For people (and spiders) anonymously browsing your site, I would omit the address entirely rather than display it obfuscated, or disallow them access to whichever pages contain user information.

Answer (score 1):

Are the email adresses yours? (your company?) or are those user email adresses.

For user adresses I would use some obfuscation or a login wall.
For personal email adresses I would not use any walls but I'd make sure everyone has some sort of spam filter.

Answer (score 0):

I just inject the email address via JavaScript.

```
var e = ["m", "o", "c", ".", "l", "i", "a",
         "m", "g", "@", "s", "m", "a", "i",
         "l", "l", "i", "w", ".", "r", ".",
         "j", ".", "a"];

$(".email").text( e.reverse().join("") );
```

It's obviously not going to keep out spammers who either manually trawl the web or parse the crawled pages and execute the JavaScript before extracting email addresses, but I doubt many go to that trouble.

Comment: "I doubt many go to that trouble." That's the problem with obfuscation in the first place.  It's all based on conjecture about what the spam scrapers will and won't do.

Comment: @Andy Yes, but if you accept that it's a deterrent rather than a fix, then it's possibly worthwhile.

Comment: Hackers _could_ decrypt your hashed+salted passwords in your database, so does that mean you may as well just store them as plain text? Given the option is this, non-obfuscated addresses, or some sort of captcha system, I think it's a good compromise, and takes very little time to implement. Even if it won't prevent 100% of scrapers, it's better than nothing.

Comment: The cost of code is non-zero.  Code is not free.  It's all about tradeoffs.  It might be "better than nothing" if the code cost nothing, but it doesn't.

Comment: We can explore what methods spammers use all day to get their email adresses, but I'd be willing to bet a *lot* of them just take the raw page HTML and regex it for valid addresses. Blocking those smaller-scale shops for the price of a couple of lines of code is the deal of the century.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that it's not worth it. Either the page contains an email address which can be read by a user-agent with permission or it doesn't. Obfuscating it detracts from the semantic value of the web, restricts to specific types of user agents such as those which can execute JavaScript or those which have a UI and a user sitting at that UI.

If you're going to display an email address then you should just display it mailto: and all, go one further and make it part of an [hCard](http://microformats.org/wiki/hcard-examples), link back to the user's XFN profile page and encourage user agents of the future to use this rich semantic data. Otherwise simply don't display an email address.

Comment: "restricts to ... those which have a UI and a user sitting at that UI" - I think that is the point, not everyone is eager to take part in complete and easy discoverability.

Comment: @Greg, a user wants to search for someone, or check whether they already have a person in their address book. They could search their browser history, maybe crawl semantically linked pages to the current one, perhaps it does some other magic which we couldn't imagine yet. Obfuscating this prevents future innovation.