# what is the best way to publicly display an email?

Tags: security, email, contacts

I'm wondering what is the safest way to display an email address publicly and what are the reasons for doing so?
E.g. I have often seen xxxx [at] domain [dot] com, etc. Is this the safest and clearest way?

Comment: The clearest way is, obviously, `john.doe@example.com`. What do you mean by publicly? In a contact page? In a user profile page?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it worth obfuscating email addresses on the web these days?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4098408/), [What are some ways to protect emails on websites from spambots?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/308772/), [Making email addresses safe from bots on a webpage?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/163628/), [Best way to obfuscate an e-mail address on a website?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/748780/).

Comment: And possibly the best reference is on Super User: [Does email address obfuscation actually work?](http://superuser.com/questions/235937/does-email-address-obfuscation-actually-work)

Answer (score 1):

I guess not. A cleverly programmed spam parser will probably get that. I usually make a jpeg image of the address and put that on a public page. Guess that's almost 100% save.

Comment: Unless you strive to make that image illegible, i.e. CAPTCHA-like, I don't think it's a big improvement.

Comment: How will the parser know which image contains the email? Unless the parser goes through EVERY image of your page and checks the result for a valid email address (which would be insane) it IS a big improvement!

Answer (score 1):

I find the easiest approach to be to post my address in the clear/with a normal unobfuscated link, and to let GMail's spam filters take care of the rest. I get very, very little spam.